# Can't induce error on $db_connect->select_db($name); ? PHP

Tags: php

I am a student.

I'm trying to deliberately induce an error in

```
$db_connect->select_db($db_name);
```

to check the error handling, but it won't give out an error?

The actual database name is 'cart', but i am using 'cartxx' to try and induce an error, but nothing happens, it runs as if there is no error. I don't have a database named 'cartxx'.

```
<?php

session_start();

$host = 'localhost'; // connects to the host server

$db_name = 'cartxx'; // name of the database we are connecting to
$db_username = 'root'; // username for database
$db_password = ''; // password for database

$db_connect = new mysqli($host, $db_username, $db_password); // connect to mysql



// If error
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo('Connection to database failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


// Select database
$db_connect->select_db($db_name);


// If error
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Connection to database {$db_name} has failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass default db name in connection string directly. if you need connect to one more database you can use select statment

```
$db_connect = new mysqli($host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
```

for more :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Okay, thank you for that. just most examples i see everyone selects the database outside of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli::selectdb` will NOT return false if you give him an incorrect database name.

This function suits better a "i want to switch from database X to database Y" scenario, and will stay connected to database X if database Y is not found.

You can check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.select-db.php) for this function.

A better way to select the database at connection is to use the [mysqli constructor](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.construct.php).